# Break While Loop adding "last" to <div>

Tags: php, css, wordpress, loops, while-loop

In WordPress, I'm using this:

```
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
echo "<div class='test'>test</div>";
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I'd now like it so for every 2nd element, it would add the "last" class to the div, so the final code could be:

```
<div class='test'>test</div>
<div class='test last'>test</div>
<div class='test'>test</div>
<div class='test last'>test</div>
<div class='test'>test</div>
<div class='test last'>test</div>.....
```

Many thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use WordPress' built-in post count field, $wp_query->current_post

```
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
   <div class="test <?=$wp_query->current_post % 2 == 0 ? "last" : "";?>">test</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 0;
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) {
    $wp_query->the_post(); 
    $i++
    if ($i %% 2){ 
        echo "<div class='test last'>test</div>";
    } 
    else{
        echo "<div class='test'>test</div>";
    }
endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Many thanks for such a speedy and helpful reply, genesis. That looks like it makes perfect sense to me. Will try shortly.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $wp_query->have_posts(); $i++) {
    $wp_query->the_post(); 
    echo ($i %% 2) ? "<div class='test last'>test</div>" : "<div class='test'>test</div>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. In this case I went with onions response above. Thanks again for the help